# Storing and Accessing node attributes python networkx

Tags: python, attributes, networkx

I have a network of nodes created using python `networkx`. i want to store information in nodes such that i can access the information later based on the node label (the name of the node) and the field that in which the information has been stored (like node attributes). the information stored can be a string or a number I wish to do so in a manner such that if `xyz` is a node:

then I want to save two or three fields having strings like the date of birth of `xyz` `dob=1185`, the place of birth of `xyz` `pob=usa`, and the day of birth of `xyz` `dayob=monday`.

I know that i can use `G.add_node` has the attribute dictionary field in it...but I can't seem to access it for a particular field. if there is any other way i would appreciate it.

i then want to compare `xyz` with other nodes in the networks having the same information in common. i.e. intersection of node `xyz` with node `abc` based on date of bith, place of birth and day of birth

e.g for if nodes `xyz` and `abc` have an edge print their respective `dob`s, their `pob`s and their `dayob`s

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As you say, it's just a matter of adding the attributes when adding the nodes to the graph

```python
G.add_node('abc', dob=1185, pob='usa', dayob='monday')
```

or as a dictionary

```
G.add_node('abc', {'dob': 1185, 'pob': 'usa', 'dayob': 'monday'})
```

To access the attributes, just access them as you would with any dictionary

```
G.node['abc']['dob'] # 1185
G.node['abc']['pob'] # usa
G.node['abc']['dayob'] # monday
```

You say you want to look at attributes for connected nodes. Here's a small example on how that could be accomplished.

```
for n1, n2 in G.edges_iter():
    print G.node[n1]['dob'], G.node[n2]['dob']
    print G.node[n1]['pob'], G.node[n2]['pob']
    # Etc.
```

As of networkx 2.0, G.edges_iter() has been replaced with G.edges(). This also applies to nodes. We set `data=True` to access attributes. The code is now:

```
for n1, n2 in list(G.edges(data=True)):
    print G.node[n1]['dob'], G.node[n2]['dob']
    print G.node[n1]['pob'], G.node[n2]['pob']
    # Etc.
```

**NOTE:** In **networkx 2.4**, `G.node[]` has been replaced with `G.nodes[]`.

Comment: Similarly for edges, you may use `G.edge[u][v]['foo']` to access the attribute `foo` of the edge (u, v).

Comment: And what if you want a list of all the attributes related to given node, is there a `G.node['abc'].all_attributes()` method that returns a list of all attribute keys?

Comment: @kuanb `G.node['abc']` is a dictionary, so you can use the regular dictionary methods, e.g. `G.node['abc'].keys()`.

Comment: I just ran into this problem as well. The only thing I would add to the answer above is to ensure that you include `**` ahead of your dictionary, otherwise the it will be parsed as multiple arguments.

Comment: if you use "G.add_nodes_from()" in the beginning, how can you set attributes for them? For instance, `Bi=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(G_df, source=0,target=1) `, how to set different attributes for source and targets?

Answer (score 56):

Additionally, you don't have to just assign the attributes when the node is added.  Even after it's been added you can still set them directly.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
#see comment below code for recent versions of networkx.
G.nodes[1]['name'] = 'alpha'
G.nodes[2]['name'] = 'omega'

G.nodes[1]['name']
> 'alpha'
```

**Note:** For versions before 2.4, use `G.node[]` instead of `G.nodes[]`. See [deprecation notes.](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.4.html#deprecations)

You can also use `set_node_attributes` ([documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html)) which will let you set an attribute for multiple nodes at the same time:

**edit**

```
#use the next line if it's networkx version 1.x
#nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'cost', {1:3.5, 2:56})

#use the next line if it's networkx version 2.x
#nx.set_node_attributes(G, {1:3.5, 2:56}, 'cost')

#or for something that works for 1.x or 2.x
nx.set_node_attributes(G, values = {1:3.5, 2:56}, name='cost')

G.node[1]['cost']
> 3.5
```

Similar approaches can be used to set edge attributes.

Comment: Note that in version 2.x of networkx the order of the second and third arguments of `set_node_attributes()` has switched, so it would be `nx.set_node_attributes(G, {1:3.5, 2:56}, 'cost')`

Answer (score 8):

As of `networkx` v2.0, you can use:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('abc', dob=1185, pob='usa', dayob='monday')
nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'dob')
> {'abc': 1185}
```

You can access this dictionary as usual:

```
{'abc': 1185}['abc']
> 1185
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently now

```
G.node[1]['name'] = 'alpha'
```

do not work anymore.

I used this : https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html

adding an s at node :

```
G.nodes[1]['name'] = 'alpha'
```

Comment: Note: For versions before 2.4, use G.node[] instead of G.nodes[]. See deprecation notes (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.4.html#deprecations)

Answer (score 0):

To add attributes as dictionary you can do the following

```
g.add_node('node_id', **{"attr1": "val1", "attr2": "val2"})
```

p.s.  if you don't add `**` you'll get exception:
`TypeError: add_node() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`