# Networkx: how get attribute color from the graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have graph [image: graph] and I need to get color of nodes. 
I try to use

```
color = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'color')
```

But it returns empty dictionary.
What I do wrong?
Graph was generated with

```
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, 0.05)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, G.nodes(), node_size=20, node_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos, alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned a color to the nodes.  In your command to plot the graph so that it could be visualized, you happened to tell it to use blue.  But that is not the same as assigning a color to the nodes themselves.  Similarly, if you had assigned an attribute to the nodes, say that their color is red, that won't affect the color used in the plot.

You can see more about adding node attributes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13698352/2966723).

Answer (score -2):

Just your node hasn't attribute color.
Your graph has such attribute

UPD:

but if you wanna see the color of nodes you can use

```
plt_.properties()['facecolor']
```

with output

> array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

first three elements of this list is color in RGB format

Comment: Don't you think this can be elaborated?

Comment: I think, that attribute for node with name 'color' doesn't affect on color of node in plot.  Attribute node_color in function nx.draw_networkx_nodes() affect on color of node on plot