# nx.get_node_attributes in networkx returning an empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Here is the code:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1,2,3,4,5])
G[0]['color']="red"
G[1]['color']="yellow"
G[2]['color']="red"
G[3]['color']="green"
G[4]['color']="green"
G[5]['color']="yellow"
print(nx.get_node_attributes(G,'color'))
```

As strange as it is, I get an empty dictionary. Does anyone know the reason of it? Or is there any other possible ways? 
Reference link about a similar issue: [Networkx: how get attribute color from the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977726/networkx-how-get-attribute-color-from-the-graph/42980947)

I know that the following is the correct way to use the `get_node_attributes` method, but is this the only way to use it?

```
>>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3],color='red')
>>> color=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'color')
>>> color[1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing and Accessing node attributes python networkx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698352/storing-and-accessing-node-attributes-python-networkx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in the [documentation for adding attributes to nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/tutorial/tutorial.html#node-attributes):

> **Node attributes**
>
> Add node attributes using `add_node()`, `add_nodes_from()` or `G.node`
>
> ```
> >>> G.add_node(1, time='5pm')
> >>> G.add_nodes_from([3], time='2pm')
> >>> G.node[1]
> {'time': '5pm'}
> >>> G.node[1]['room'] = 714
> >>> G.nodes(data=True)
> [(1, {'room': 714, 'time': '5pm'}), (3, {'time': '2pm'})]
> ```

This isn't a bug; you're just not setting the attributes correctly.

Comment: Worth adding mention of `nx.set_node_attributes` which lets you set attributes after the node is defined.