# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' when converting graph to numpy matrix [NetworkX]

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, networkx

l would like to transform a graph to a numpy matrix

My graph has  40 nodes `(G.nodes)` and each node is associated with with a vector of 50 values.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.balanced_tree(3,3)
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
for v in G.nodes():
    G.node[v] = np.random.random(50)
```

What l would like to get ?
since l have a 40 nodes, l need to get a matrix of `(40,50)`.
How can l get that from `G.node[v]` ?

What l have tried ?

```
matrix_graph_features=G.node[:]
```

l got the following error :

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing and Accessing node attributes python networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698352/storing-and-accessing-node-attributes-python-networkx)

Comment: looks like `node` is a dictionary, or dictionary like. `:` is for  lists and numpy arrays.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is.  Can you give explicitly what you want the output to be.  It's not clear what "a matrix of `(40,50)`" means

Comment: 40 examples and each example has 50 values hence a matrix of (40,50)

Comment: G.node[0]= vector of 50 values ..... G.node[39]= vector of 50 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to store the data associated with each node correctly.  Since you are using a generator `balanced_tree`, it is easier to add as attributes afterwards than during graph construction.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13702743) also shows how to add attributes when adding nodes as an alternative.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

propname = "vals" # use a more meaningful name for your application!
G = nx.balanced_tree(3,3)
#A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
for v in G.nodes():
    G.node[v][propname] = np.random.random(50)
```

Now to access the data, you can either iterate using `G.nodes(data=True)`, or if you want to access a specific data attribute for all nodes, you can use the function `nx.get_node_attribues`.  Below I show how to obtain the random values above, in a 40x50 matrix:

```
M = np.array([v for k, v in nx.get_node_attributes(G, propname).iteritems()])

print(G.number_of_nodes())
>>> 40
print(M.shape)
>>> (40, 50)
```

Now your data is in 2d array form, it is easy to perform further operations on, e.g. `M.mean(), M.std()`, etc..
NOTE: you should be careful with the ordering of the rows in this matrix, particularly if you add any new nodes at runtime.